# Center Content of v-container on Mobile while using Fill-Height Property in Vuetify

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I've been struggling with an issue for a while now and I was hoping that a fix would be released and the issue would resolve itself. It did not unfortunately. I have this basic code in my App.vue that is using vuetify elements:

```
<template>
  <v-app class="app" id="inspire">
    <v-content>
      <v-container class="fill-height" fluid>
        <v-row align="center" justify="center">
          <v-col class="text-center">
            <v-card outlined>
              <span>Source</span>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

This looks fine. However, when I scale down to a mobile device, the v-card is not centered, but pushed to the left. See image below. When I remove the fill-height property on the container, everything looks correctly, but I would like to center the v-card vertically on my page. Is this a Vuetify issue? I could not find this exact issue described anywhere else. Is there maybe something wrong in my setup?

[image: Example]

Thanks in advance!

Jeroen

Comment: Can't seem to recreate it with [the code you posted](https://www.codeply.com/p/IQ5lKUL4xT) so maybe it's something with the content of the header or footer?

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks for testing! I simplified the code and updated it in the post, but even with only this the v-card is off-centered

Comment: @Zim, what happens if you look at this example and open dev tools and select a mobile device? For me it's pushed to the left. However, when I remove fill-height, it's nicely centered

Comment: Sorry, this was the example I was referring to: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/centered/

Answer (score 0):

The `margin-right: -12px` and `margin-left: -12px` that come from the `.container.fill-height > .row` element are causing the issue. Doesn't seem that they are aware otherwise they would add `margin: auto` of some kind to resolve it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try. So you think adding margin: auto to row elements in css will resolve the issue?

Comment: I would just try adding it to that one and see if that solves your problem! The other rows in the structure need that negative margin to show correctly